# python, global name not defined

Tags: python-2.7

I put some helper functions in  a separate file helper.py:

```
def funct1(data1):
    # doing something
    return data1

def funct2(data2):
    temp = funct1(data2) 
    # doing something
    return data2
```

I import this helper.py in another file, but got an error `"global name funct1 is not defined"`

```
import helper as hp

hp.funct2(somedata)
```

Comment: Can not reproduce. What is `doing something` doing?

Comment: sorry, I'm embarrassed.

Comment: It turns out there is a typing missing in my code, sorry.

Really appreciate your help, though.

Otherwise, I would not have a closer look to my code